# Can a power series conditionally converge outside its radius of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

Having learned about conditional and absolute convergence of series, I was confused when the methods used to find the interval of convergence of a power series seemed to consider only absolute convergence.

Let $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty b_n (x-c)^n$ be a power series with $\lim_{n\to \infty} \lvert \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} \rvert = R$ where $R \ne 0$.

Usually, to find the interval and radius of convergence of $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty b_n (x-c)^n$, we check absolute convergence. Let $a_n = \lvert b_n(x-c)^n \rvert$. Using the Ratio Test,

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \lvert \frac{b_{n+1}(x-c)^{n+1}}{b_n(x-c)^n} \rvert $$

$$= \lvert x-c \rvert\lim_{n\to \infty} \lvert \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \rvert$$

$$= \frac{\lvert x-c \rvert}{R}$$

By the Ratio Test, $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n$ converges for $\frac{\lvert x-c \rvert}{R} < 1 \iff \lvert x-c \rvert < R$. Absolute convergence implies convergence, so $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty b_n (x-c)^n$ is convergent for $\lvert x-c \rvert < R$. For the endpoints $x = c$ or $x = -c$, the Ratio Test for $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n$ is inconclusive, so we usually test $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty b_n (x-c)^n$ using methods other than the Ratio Test at the endpoints. We usually consider $[-R+c,R+c], (-R+c,R+c], [-R+c,R+c),$ or $(-R+c,R+c)$ to be the radius of convergence depending on the convergence of the series at the endpoints.

According to the calculations above, $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n$ is divergent for $\lvert x-c \rvert > R$. However, this only means that
$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty b_n (x-c)^n$ is not absolutely convergent. Could it be conditionally convergent for some $\lvert x-c \rvert > R$?

I would be grateful if you could explain this in a way that is understandable to an undergraduate student like myself. Thank you.

Comment: Let $|x|>R$ and show that the terms of the series eventually increase in absolute value, so that the $n$th term doesn't go to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's set $c=0$; it just complicates the notation without contributing any insight.

The basic fact from which existence of convergence *radiuses* follow is this:

- Suppose the power series $\sum_n b_nz^n$ converges (even conditionally) at $z$. Then it converges (absolutely) at *every* $w$ with $|w|<|z|$.

*Proof.* If the series $\sum_n b_nz^n$ converges, then its terms must at least be bounded by some number, say $|b_nz^n| \le M$ for some $M\in \mathbb R$ and all $n$. But then $|b_nw^n| = |b_n z^n|(|w|/|z|)^n \le M(|w|/|z|)^n$, and since by assumption $|w|/|z|<1$ this means that $\sum_n b_nw^n$ converges absolutely by comparison with the geometric series $\sum_n M(|w|/|z|)^n$.

Fundamentally, the radius of convergence is just
$$ \sup \bigl\{ |w| \bigm| \text{the power series converges at }w \bigr\} $$
(with several of alternative characterizations that can help with *calculating* it). Therefore the series *cannot* converge outside the radius of convergence, because if it did, that would just make the radius of convergence bigger instead!