Need help understanding this proof: the derivative of a power series has its radius of convergence equal to that of the power series
I have two questions regarding the following proof:



In the second last line we have proven that the differentiated series cannot be absolutely convergent. How do we know that it is not conditionally convergent either?

If we find the radius of convergence of the derived series by finding the limit of ${a_n}/{a_{n+1}}$ as n tends to infinity, we get the radius of convergence as R. Isn't this enough for the proof?



If it's conditionally convergent at $x$ with $R<|x|$, then it's absolutely convergent at $y$ with $R<|y|<|x|$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186323/can-a-power-series-conditionally-converge-outside-its-radius-of-convergence

@mr_e_man Thanks! This answers the first doubt. What about the second one?

For the first question, as pointed out by mr_e_man, suppose that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_n x^{n-1}$ is conditionally convergent for some $|x|>R$. In particular, $M:=\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\left\lvert na_n x^{n-1}\right\rvert<\infty$. For $y$ such that $|y|\in (R,|x|)$, we would derive the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\lvert a_n y^{n-1}\rvert$, since
$$
n\lvert a_n y^{n-1}\rvert=n\left\lvert a_n x^{n-1}\right\rvert \left(\frac{\lvert y\rvert}{\lvert x\rvert}\right)^{n-1}\leqslant M\left(\frac{\lvert y\rvert}{\lvert x\rvert}\right)^{n-1},
$$
which would contradict the fact that the radius of convergence is $R$.
For the second question, indeed, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}/a_n$ exists, then we would also get that $(n+1)a_{n+1}/(na_n)$ converges to the same limit. However, there is no reason that such a limit exist (for example $a_n=1$ for $n$ even and $a_n=n$ for $n$ odd) hence one has to do the general reasoning that was presented. Nevertheless, you can use Hadamard formula, saying that the radius of convergence is the inverse of  $\limsup_n \lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}$.

Why wouldn't the limit exist?  The limit is the radius and if the radius exists then so should the limit right? Are there any examples where a_n/a_n+1 does not have a limit but the radius exists?

You could very well have $a_n=1$ for $n$ even and $a_n=n$ for $n$ odd. The radius of convergence is one$. I have edited the post to illustrate this.

I am confused. Our teacher derived the expression of radius from the ratio test. We used the ratio test to show that for the series to converge | a(n+1).x^n+1/(an.x^n)|<1  and hence, |x|<|an/a(n+1)| which we denote by R. If we consider your example then for n=even, we will have |x|<|1/(n+1)=0. Then how can the radius be 1? Please point out where I am going wrong.

The radius of convergence of a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is a number $R\in [0\infty]$ such that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges absolutely if $|z|<R$ and does not converge if $|z|>R$. In the previous example, the absolute convergence for $|z|<1$ can be seen for that of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\lvert z\rvert^n$ and if $|z|>1$, the term $a_nz^n$ does not converge to $0$. Probably what your teacher said is: if $\lim_n a_n/a_{n+1}$ exists, then the radius of convergence can be expressed in terms of this limit.

Thanks a lot! I understand now. Thank you for your patience
